# Virtualize a running physical server without reboot?

Tags: virtualization

I need to virtualize a running physical linux (Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 3 (Taroon Update 9)) server. The server can not be rebooted for a normal virtualization process. Can it be done on a running server? Ideas on how? Software that supports such a process?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Free VMware vCenter Converter Standalone 4.0 will solve my problem